# HDMI sound option disappears when I install the latest updates to Ubuntu Vivid 15

Tags: sound, hdmi

After install of  Ubuntu Vidid 15 I can select sound options and then see the HDMI option for output. All is well.

I then run software 'Upgrade' and as soon as this completes the HDMI option is no longer available ?

Is there a way you can 'back out' the updates just applied ?

Is there anything I should do to debug this further.

This is a brand new installation,

Thanks in advance Dave

```
dave@dave-desktop:~$ uname -a
Linux dave-desktop 3.19.0-18-generic #18-Ubuntu SMP Tue May 19 18:31:35 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

dave@dave-desktop:~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC892 Analog [ALC892 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC892 Digital [ALC892 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Comment: sounds like you're asking two questions - one about rolling-back updates and the other about debugging your sound problem. Which is it that you most want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `3.19.0-18 kernel` has a bug that breaks HDMI sound on intel HDA. Rollback your kernel by running

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.19.0-18-generic
```

Note this will also remove `linux-generic*` and `linux-image-generic*` which means Ubuntu will never offer to upgrade your kernel ever again, so you need to remember to check if it's fixed in a new kernel in a couple days and reinstall those packages.

Comment: Fixed issue straight away...thank you so much.

Comment: from  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1457369  :   This bug was fixed in the package linux - 3.19.0-20.20