# Only analog sound device in 15.04, HDMI device was accessible before

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, 15.04, hdmi

as the title suggests I can't choose HDMI audio output anymore, the only available sound device is analog. I could choose HDMI audio output before, but now it is missing.

Comment: Is anything connected to HDMI? Does that display work?

Comment: There is recent bug on hdmi audio : http://askubuntu.com/questions/627587/hdmi-sound-option-disappears-when-i-install-the-latest-updates-to-ubuntu-vivid-1   . Bug as been reported : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1458478

Comment: yes, the display works, i can watch something on it with the sound coming from the laptop boxes. I should add that it is a mini-DP output, i have a miniDP to HDMI plug.